# .htaccess поменять местами деректор. в юрл

Tags: php, файлы, .htaccess, url

Здрасте.
Есть сайт.ру, есть файл.пхп в котором выводится цилк с юрл.
Есть штакес вот с таким содержанием:

```
RewriteRule ^файл/([^/]*)$ /файл.пхп?url=$1 [L]
```

Вид ссылки: сайт.ру/файл/юрл
Надо сделать: сайт.ру/юрл/файл

Кручу-верчу и не могу сообразить. Не силен в этом. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: дак как крутили вертели то? вроде местами поменять надо просто в правиле?

Comment: ага и не работает. я уже и печеньки чистил и крутил-вертел. Можно пример? Может я что не так делаю...

Comment: дак вы покажите, как именно вы делаете. давайте с конкретикой а не это файл.пхп

Comment: ладно
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)$ /file.php?url=$1 [L]   Вид ссылки: site.ru/file/url Надо сделать: site.ru/url/file